# Why won't the variable increase 2 times

Tags: c#, console

I wrote a class and 2 new constructors, but the `num` increases its value only 1 time and I don't know why.

```
using System;

Program1 one = new Program1("name1");
Program1 two = new Program1("name2");

class Program1
{
    private int num = 0;

    public Program1(string name)
    {
        num++;
        Console.WriteLine($"It is your {num} object");
        Console.WriteLine($"{name} is your object");
    }
}
```

Console:

```
It is your 1 object
name1 is your object
It is your 1 object
name2 is your object
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `num` to be a `static` field/property?

Comment: This is where correct nomenclature can help with understanding. You don't have _"2 new constructors"_. You have one constructor (`public Program1(string name)`) that gets invoked twice, once for each of two _instances_, each of which gets its own instance state; in this case `num` (initialized to zero at construction time, but later incremented by one). By changing it to a `static` class member (rather than an _instance_ member) - as everyone is suggesting - you end up with state that I'd not associated withe each instance, but with the class as a whole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, `num` is an *instance* member of the class. So, each time you create a new instance, `num` is a different field with its own value.

If you want its value to increase regardless of the instance, you can turn it into a `static` field or property:

```
private static int num = 0;
```

Now, each time you call `new Program1(someString)`, the value of `num` will increase.

Be aware that in this case, each instance will *not* have its own value of `num`. To test this, let's add the following method to the class

```
public void PrintNum()
{
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

Now, the following code:

```
Program1 one = new Program1("name1");
Program1 two = new Program1("name2");

Console.Write("one.PrintNum: "); one.PrintNum();
Console.Write("two.PrintNum: "); two.PrintNum();
```

...will produce:

```
It is your 1 object
name1 is your object
It is your 2 object
name2 is your object
one.PrintNum: 2
two.PrintNum: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `num` is not [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static), `one.num` and `two.num` are variables in different instances of Program1.

If you want to have the same `num` value in all instances of Program1, you can try

```cs
class Program1
{
    private static int num = 0;

    public Program1(string name)
    {
        num++;
        Console.WriteLine($"It is your {num} object");
        Console.WriteLine($"{name} is your object");
    }
}
```